# Rails 4 Checkbox Collection: can't get include_hidden: false to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to get the `include_hidden: false` option for checkboxes to work. I've read the documentation, looked at the tests, seen a lot of issues, but it doesn't work for me.

This line should give me a list of checkboxes without the extra hidden one:

`collection_check_boxes :message, :videos, @videos, :first, :last, include_hidden: false`

What am I doing wrong? I've even tried the example in the tests, that one doesn't work for me.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cdc00aba62ffb0f0af452f5152aafeb5e490962e/actionview/test/template/form_collections_helper_test.rb#L231

Answer (score 0):

After much research with a coworker, we found that the code is not in 4.0-4.1, and only appears in 4.2 beta. Will submit an issue.